# Error to convert from string to date

Tags: java, date

I am using a method to calculate the difference in days between two dates. Before performing the calculations need convering the date string to date, which is causing me a problem.

```
public static int difDate(String data1, String data2) throws ParseException{  
    GregorianCalendar ini = new GregorianCalendar();  
    GregorianCalendar fim = new GregorianCalendar();  
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy");  
    ini.setTime(sdf.parse(data1));  
    fim.setTime(sdf.parse(data2));  
    long dt1 = ini.getTimeInMillis();  
    long dt2 = fim.getTimeInMillis();  
    return (int) (((dt2 - dt1) / 86400000)+1);  
}
```

This code is generating an exception:

```
12-26 07:31:38.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11452): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

12-26 07:31:38.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11452): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
12-26 07:31:38.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11452):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3673)
12-26 07:31:38.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11452):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4278)
12-26 07:31:38.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11452):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17430)
12-26 07:31:38.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11452):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-26 07:31:38.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11452):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-26 07:31:38.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11452):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
12-26 07:31:38.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11452):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5092)
12-26 07:31:38.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11452):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 07:31:38.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11452):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-26 07:31:38.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11452):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
12-26 07:31:38.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11452):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:564)
12-26 07:31:38.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11452):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-26 07:31:38.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11452): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-26 07:31:38.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11452):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 07:31:38.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11452):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-26 07:31:38.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11452):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3668)
12-26 07:31:38.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11452):    ... 11 more
12-26 07:31:38.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11452): Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "26.11.2013" (at offset 2)
12-26 07:31:38.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11452):    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:622)
12-26 07:31:38.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11452):    at com.sisteplantbrasil.util.DateHelper.DiferencaEntreDatas(DateHelper.java:58)
12-26 07:31:38.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11452):    at com.sisteplantbrasil.WorkOrderHistoricFilter.onBtnActionClick(WorkOrderHistoricFilter.java:222)
12-26 07:31:38.027: E/AndroidRuntime(11452):    ... 14 more

Anyone know how I can fix this problem?

```
ini.setTime(sdf.parse(data1));
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input is 26.11.2013 instead of 26/11/2013. Either change the format of the input or change the way you create the `SimpleDateFormat`

```
SimpleDateFormat(dd/MM/yyyy);
```

to

```
SimpleDateFormat(dd.MM.yyyy);
```

that's why it throws this exception